# Error due to ballerina distribution and OS architecture mismatch

Tags: linux, docker, ballerina

We're using a Dockerfile that uses manual ballerina distribution installation. This docker build is failing on Mac M1 due to following error.

```
#0 208.0 2023-01-10 04:09:46 (912 KB/s) - ‘ballerina-2201.2.3-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb’ saved [191867000/191867000]
#0 208.0 
#0 208.1 dpkg: error processing archive ballerina-2201.2.3-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb (--install):
#0 208.1  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
#0 208.1 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 208.1  ballerina-2201.2.3-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget 'https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/2201.2.3/ballerina-2201.2.3-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb';     dpkg -i ballerina-2201.2.3-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb]: exit code: 1
```

One way to tackle this issue is updating the Dockerfile to use different ballerina distributions depending on the OS architecture. But a ballerina distribution released for linux/arm64 architecture is not listed in official downloads page. Highly appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a manual ballerina distribution installation, we can use [Ballerina zip distribution](https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/2201.8.3/ballerina-2201.8.3-swan-lake.zip) and install a supported arm64 supported JVM.

Also for runtime images, instead of a using Ballerina, we can use a JRE image that supports the required platform.